# Geo Query not working with sub collections - Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, geo

I am trying to retrieve all the nearby restaurants using Geo Queries in flutter. The locations are added in each restaurant document under the 'restaurants' collection. I think the sub-collections might be causing the problem because according to the GeoFlutterFire Documentation, all the locations are placed in a single collection. Is there a way to make this work in sub-collection? If not, what approach should I use?

```
_getUserLocation() async {
      final location1 = Location();
      final geo = Geoflutterfire();
      // var collectionReference =
      //     FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurants');
      // double radius = 50;
      // String field = 'position';
      _serviceEnabled = await location1.serviceEnabled();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        _serviceEnabled = await location1.requestService();
        if (!_serviceEnabled) {
          return;
        }
      }
      _permissionGranted = await location1.hasPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
        _permissionGranted = await location1.requestPermission();
        if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
          return;
        }
      }
      // final location = Location.instance.getLocation();

      // await location.then((value) {
      //   latitude = value.latitude;
      //   longitude = value.longitude;
      // });
      GeoFirePoint myLocation =
          geo.point(latitude: 6.55526689, longitude: -73.13373892);

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc('NUdKiZVLblbceWVRjONFQwW5Wg72')
          .collection('locations')
          .doc('NUdKiZVLblbceWVRjONFQwW5Wg72')
          .set({'name': 'Home', 'position': myLocation.data});

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      GeoFirePoint center =
          geo.point(latitude: 7.08594109039762, longitude: 286.95225338731285);
      var collectionReference =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users.locations');
      var geoRef = geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference);

      Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geoRef.within(
          center: center, radius: 150, field: 'position', strictMode: true);

      stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
        print(documentList.length);
      });
    }
```

The output I am getting is:

> flutter: 0

[image]